# azure DevOps - Service connection to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, devops

I am trying to create a service connection to Azure with below steps:
1- I use same user for Azure and Azure DevOps
2- in the Project setting -> service connection -> new service connection
Azure resource Manager -> Service principal (Automatic)
but It can not find my subscription.

anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have Azure Active Directory level permissions? You will also need Owner level Subscription Permissions on the subscription as displayed in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-using-automated-security). You can add a service connection manually, you don't have to use the automated process as per the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-with-an-existing-service-principal)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I modified the user permission on AAD and issue resolved.

Comment: Now can other users and projects use the created service connection ? is it globally?

Comment: Yeah, once the Service Connection exists in DevOps it can be used by all members of DevOps with permissions to use Service Connections. Azure permissions don't matter after it's been added to DevOps